# IE screwiness (won't render empty cell in asp:listview)

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, iis, listview

I have an asp:listview using a css class.  On my dev system (VS2008), it renders correctly in Chrome, IE and FireFox.  On our production server (IIS 2.0), IE will not apply the style to an empty cell - but cells that contain text/whatever are fine.  Chrome and FireFox still render fine.  The style I want is a thin line on the bottom of each row, kind of like a row separator.  Any idea what I can try to fix this?

Here is the css I assign to the Item and AltItem templates

```
.itemtemplate
{
    background-color: White;
}
.itemtemplate TD
{
  border-bottom:solid 1px #eae9e1; 
  border-right:solid 1px #eae9e1;
}
```

Oh, one other thing.  If I change the background color in the css to say, orange, then the empty cells render with a border.

Comment: Have you tried to determine whether the CSS file actually makes it to the browser when you've deployed on the real server?  Does it work in any other browser?  It's unlikely that this is a server issue *unless* the server is not supplying the CSS at all, due to a broken path in your `<link>` tag or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IE, a cell must have content of some kind to be displayed properly. Try programmatically adding an `&nbsp;` entity to create empty content.

**Edit:**
To make sure that the `&nbsp;` makes it into the html you may need to run your Eval through a method and return the result of the method:

```
...Text='<%# GetItemText(Eval("EmployeeNumber").ToString()) %>'
```

With the code behind like:

```
public string GetItemText(string empNum)
{
    return (String.IsNullOrEmpty(empNum) ? "&nbsp;" : empNum;
}
```

Comment: I still have the same problem after changing the text attribute of the itemtemplate like this: Text='&nbsp;<%# Eval("EmployeeNumber") %>

Comment: @Curtis - have you verified the output of the ListItem to make sure that the `&nbsp;` is actually making it into the html?

Comment: Joel-no, the &nbsp; does not appear to be in the html.  Any idea how to add it?

Comment: Joel - thanks.  Running the string through a function like that works.

Comment: @Curtis - one of my favorite low-down-dirty-tricks. Probably not THE best solution out there, but it's easy and fast.

Answer (score 0):

Put `&nbsp;` into your empty cell.

If I remember correctly, the `<td>` isn't supposed to be empty ever according to the HTML spec anyways, so you really should always have something in the cell.

Comment: I still have the same problem after changing the text attribute of the itemtemplate like this: Text='&nbsp;<%# Eval("EmployeeNumber") %>'